# I want to access a relationship through an inherited class

Tags: python, django

See the contrived example below. If I have an Owner and I want to access all their Cars or all their Bicycles, I can't think of a clean way to do that. Please note that I can't make Vehicle an abstract class, since the VehicleIncident class is using it in a FK relationship.

```
from django.db import models
from foo import Owner


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)


class VehicleIncident(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)


class Car(Vehicle):
    steering_wheel = models.CarPartField()


class Bicycle(Vehicle):
    handlebars = models.HandlebarField()
```

If I know the owner (User), how can I get a specific vehicle type?

This throws an error:

> object has no attribute

```
owner.bicycle_set.all()
```

Comment: Does `Bicycle.objects.filter(owner=user)` work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Hmm, I feel like I was looking for a different approach (going through the User), but your suggestion totally works.

Comment: As `Vehicle` has foreign key with `Owner` and its not abstract, `Owner` will have `vehicle_set` not `bicycle_set`. You have to use method suggested by Daniel.